# If $V=L$ and $\alpha<\aleph_1$, find a countable $\beta >\alpha$ s.t. when $x\in L_{\beta+1}$, $x\in L_{\beta}$

Tags: set-theory

Assume $V=L$. I want to show that for any countable ordinal $\alpha$, there is a countable $\beta >\alpha$ such that whenever a set of integers $x\in L_{\beta+1}$, it follows $x\in L_{\beta}$.

This is the question I should have asked last time (at least I hope).

Comment: Note that 'set of integers' here is essential - the statement isn't true for an arbitrary set $x$, for fairly trivial reasons.

Comment: WTS? What That Standsfor?

Comment: @AsafKaragila "Want to show"

Comment: Honestly now, did it *really* save you time to skip these nine characters (spaces included)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me expand on Jonathan's excellent answer.

First note (working under $V=L$) that if $x\subseteq\omega$ then $x\in L_{\omega_1}$. This is how we prove that $\sf CH$ holds in $L$. And this is true by a condensation argument.

Now. to utilize this, we want practically any limit ordinal above $\omega_1$. If $\delta>\omega_1$ is a limit ordinal, then:

1. $L_\delta$ is a model of $V=L$.
2. $L_\delta$ satisfies "There is an ordinal $\beta$ such that no new subsets of $\omega$ are added after $L_\beta$".
3. $L_\delta$ satisfies $\alpha$ is countable (and in particular $\alpha<\beta$ where $\beta$ is the least ordinal mentioned in item (2)).

So by taking a countable elementary submodel $M$ such that $L_\alpha\in M$, and then collapsing $M$ to a transitive set we get some $L_\gamma$ satisfying (2) and (3) at the same time.

Finally, $L_\gamma$ and $L_\beta$ have the same power set of $\omega$, and $\gamma$ is limit. So we get that $L_{\beta+1}$ did not add subsets to $\omega$.

Comment: Sorry, one last thing. How do we know $\alpha < \beta$? Is it impossible for $P(\omega)$ to be contained in a countable level of $L$?

Comment: Well. Every $\alpha<\omega_1$ can be coded by a subset of $\omega$, and at some point Mostowski's collapse lemma need to start working.

Comment: But you say that $L_{\delta}$ satisfies this inequality. And we haven't collapsed anything there.

Comment: I don't understand the point you're trying to make.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again, but don't we want to make sure that the formula $x \in L_{\omega_1}$ is absolute for $L_{\delta}$, in order to ensure that (2) above is true? I know that this formula is $\Delta_1$, but $L_{\delta}$ is not an inner model. I think this may be why you mentioned (1), but I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue here is. Since $\delta>\omega_1$, it computes correctly $L_{\omega_1}$ since it computes $\omega_1$ correctly.

Comment: Ok, maybe I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the collapse of a countable elementary submodel of $H(\omega_2) = L_{\omega_2}$ containing $L_\alpha$. This has the form $M = L_\gamma$ for some $\alpha < \gamma < \omega_1$. Now let $\beta = \omega_1^{M}$ and follow that $\beta$ has the required property.

Comment: Using a similar idea you can show that there can be arbitrary long (countable) gaps where no new reals appear.

Comment: +1. For the OP, the second sentence is just the condensation theorem.

Comment: I'm not sure I have the final verification correct. I see that your $\beta$ has $\alpha < \beta <\omega_1$. But to show the other part, is the point to notice that in $L_{\omega_2}$, we can prove that if $x\in L_{\omega_1+1}$, then $x\in L_{\omega_1}$? I guess I'm not sure why you chose $\omega_2$ in  particular.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 $\omega_2$ was just natural to choose but in principle you could also start with $L_{\omega_1 +1}$ take an elementary submodel of that and collapse and it will have the form $L_{\beta+1}$.